# Number of lattice points bounded by lines on plane.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, inclusion-exclusion

There are given following lines on plane:

- $A: x=0$
- $B: y=0$
- $C_{i}:y=a_{i}x+b_{i}$ for $1\le i \le n$ so that these lines intersect with first two lines ($x=0,y=0$) at non-negative coordinates.

Let $G(i)$ be the set of lattice points in area bounded by $A,B,C_{i}$

> Calculate $|G(1)\cup...\cup G(n)|$.

First of all i know that there should be used an inclusion-exclusion principle, but apart of $|G(i)|$ the rest is hard to calculate.
Should i use Pick's theorem? If so then how?

Comment: Unfortunately, Pick's theorem doesn't quite work as when $a_i$ and $b_i$ won't necessarily intersect at lattice points. However, what we can do instead is split the polygon bounded by these lines with lines parallel to the $x$-axis passing through the vertices of the polygon. This creates strips of trapeziums which we can count the lattice points in. Have a go at trying this.